# Custom Eagle Part has isolation built-in?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, eaglecad

I've just created the footprint for a QFN-56 8mmX8mm to be used with the TLC5958.

It seems like there is some sort of isolation built in to the center pad and I cannot figure it out.  In the image below, you can see that I have six vias that are to be all connected to the GND layer on the bottom.  The vias are placed here just to show the issue and won't be in those spots in the finished board.

As you can see the vias show a signal connection, but for some reason the outer polygon pour doesn't connect with the GND below the IC.

[image]

Here are the properties of the thermal pad, from what I see, there isn't anything that would cause it to just isolate itself from everything else.

[image]

**What property or anything could be causing this?**

Comment: Is there anything on the bRestrict layer?

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Nope, nothing on the bRestrict layer

Comment: Are you absolutely certain that the name of the ground layer, and the name of that pad are compatible, and have not accidentally created two different grounds

Comment: This isn't what you asked, but the corners of the pads for the ends of adjacent rows look really really close.  That tiny clearance is probably not within your board house's design rules.

Comment: @gbulmer yep! I'm absolutely sure.  I just deleted all the vias and related signals and then re-made them.  The problem still stands

Comment: @OlinLathrop Yea, I feel the same way,  I designed on the high tolerance but I'll probably pull that down to nominal pad size.

Comment: What do you see when you switch all of the layers on? If nothing, go look at the layers dialogue, because something has no visual representation. If something, go track down which layer it is. If the worst comes to the worst, maybe make a very simple PCB with the part, and put it somewhere like gist, so we an look. (Though I am off to bed now :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use the same default color scheme as i do, you have messed up line classes. Probably swapped tPlace and Dimension because the white rectangle is too white to be only tPlace.

Comment: Am I to use Dimension rather than tPlace on custom parts or the other way around?  Its weird that this is coming up now.  I've made quite a hefty library of parts and I've never had this problem

Comment: tPlace is component outline, Dimension is board outline. Poured copper keeps a gap from Dimension, that is specified in Tools/DRC/Distance or Spacing in polygon properties, whichever is greater.

Comment: I was wrong, Spacing in polygon properties is for something different. Nevertheless, distance from the grey line to blue polygon is pretty close to 40 mil, which is the default value for copper/dimension distance.

Comment: Turns out it was the tPlace and Dimension being swapped.  I'm surprised I haven't encountered this before considering how many boards I design

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you don't have things connected right in the schematic.  The ground pad should have its own pin in the symbol, and that pin should be connected to ground in the schematic.  Otherwise, you are saying they aren't supposed to be connected.